# Animating own low poly trees on my own terrain?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, tree, shader

Is there any easy way to animate my own tree models? I can't use tree creator, because it's useless for me since I am using my own terrain. My tree models are [low poly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czMWc.jpg) and I would like animate trees like [here](http://altos.bug-factory.net/www/img/tree2.webm). Do I have to write a shader for this? I found [this one](http://youtube.com/watch?v=e4MEttgakTc), but I am not sure if I can use it or how to apply it to all my trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate them in your 3D software (Blender?) and it's probably the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Didn't know about Shape Keys in blender, which really simplyfies "vertex animation". Thank You for brainstorming. :)